# ejabberd installation issue for mac

Tags: macos, installation, xmpp, ejabberd

I am installing ejabberd by using source code. I have take the clone from git : https://github.com/processone/ejabberd.git. and followed steps:
Git: brew install git
Erlang /OTP: brew install erlang

Autoconf: brew install autoconf

Automake: brew install automake

Openssl: brew install openssl

Expat: brew install expat

Libyaml: brew install libyaml

Libiconv: brew install libiconv

Sqlite: brew install sqlite

chmod +x autogen.sh
 ./autogen.sh
 export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/expat/lib"

export CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include/ -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/expat/include"

export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include/ -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/expat/include"

./configure --prefix=$HOME/my-ejabberd --enable-mysql

make

above command is working correctly. but "sudo make install" have the problem.

## Configuration files

/usr/bin/install -c -d -m 750 -g pravin //etc/ejabberd
install: pravin: Invalid argument
make: *** [install] Error 67

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

just `brew install ejabberd` for current release or `brew install ejabberd --HEAD` to install current git master HEAD